# Finding all the URL requests from a firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am building a firefox extension. In this extension, I want to see the URLs of any new webpage that the user visits. The webpage can be in a different tab or window than the current tab that the user is viewing (this should also catch the URL of pop-ups). Is there a way to find when firefox makes a GET or POST request and grab the URL?

An alternative that I am trying to avoid is going through all the tabs and manually check to see if they have loaded a new page.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Places_Developer_Guide#Observing_History) should help you out.

Comment: It's better to write an answer, and then provide a reference link than to use only use a link (as evidenced by this, now dead, link). :/

Answer (score 0):

Add the permissions "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "< all_urls>"
in your manifest.json.

In your background.js do this:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
    console.log(details.url);
},
{
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
}, 
["requestHeaders", "blocking"]);
```